# SQLiteLog: (1) no such table for Android 9

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Возникла проблема с Android 9.
Использую "стандартный" класс **MyDataBaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper**
С выходом андроид 9 появилась проблема *android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:*
То есть только на 9 не хочет работать. Базу копирует но таблиц в ней не находит. *E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table:* Может кто сталкивался с данной ситуацией?

Методы класса:

```
public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    // путь к базам
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    else DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", context.getPackageName());

    DB_NAME = databaseName;

    //openDataBase();
}


//Создаст базу, если она не создана
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, DB_NAME+" BASE ALREADY EXIST");
        //база уже есть
    }else{
        //создаем пустую базу
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, DB_NAME+" NEW BASE IS CREATED");
        try {
            copyDataBase();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, DB_NAME+" BASE COPY");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

//Проверка существования базы данных
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
    }

    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;
}

//Метод копирования базы
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Открываем поток для чтения из уже созданной нами БД
    //источник в assets
    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Путь к уже созданной пустой базе в андроиде

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // поток для записи в эту БД побайтно
    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // копирование
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    // закроем потоки
    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();

}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    return database;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572375/8211160

Comment: Спасибо. Поменял методы, все заработало. Но осталось непонятным почему не работало только на Андроид 9. Так то по смыслу вообще нигде работать не должно. Встречал подобные решения в сети, но думал что это не мой случай.

Comment: я по концовке сделал метод который сначала удаляет базу полностью и потом заново перезаписывает. Это работает на всех устройствах. Так как иначе база остается но зачищается в ноль. Логично что и таблиц поэтому в ней нет.  Конкретно про 9 андроид не знаю. Тестирую на 4.4 и 8.1